# jquery blur() used with elementS

Tags: jquery

i want to select many elements that have a custom attribute, then get each one of them and execute a code when the blur() event triggered.

```
$("[AttributeName]").blur(function(){
alert($(this).val());
}
```

i didn't want to use each() method, then verify witch one is blured ! because i don't want to go through ALL the DOM elements that have the same attribute, then make the check, because it may take a huge load of momery

Comment: That should work - you're missing the closing `);` at the end of it though. If it doesn't work try `('*[AttributeName="attrvalue"]').blur()`;

Comment: the question is even this code isn't working and the console log doesn't show any error ! lol

Comment: You're already attaching a handler to the blur event to all of the items coming from the selector. To know which one fired up the event, refer to `$(this)` in the callback.

Comment: I guess you are looking at `on` with the selector overload. which works like the old `live` `$('parent of all elements').on('blur', 'selector', function(){})`

Comment: Your code have missing bits, as spotted by @scrowler

Comment: ok @MelanciaUK when i use `$(this)` as the function call back, i get `an expected token (` in the console log .. i tried to introduce a new `var a=$(this)` nothing happens

Comment: it is not working @Bart i have any jsfiddle please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a live event handler.  The handler will be attached to the `document` element and it will execute when a `blur` event bubbles up from an element matching your `'[AttributeName]'` selector.

If you know that all the elements you're interested in will be contained within a single element, then use that instead of `document`.

`$(document).on('blur', '[AttributeName]', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});`

Comment: i think this one wont take much of memory size as if i use : each(); right ?

Comment: Right, that's the idea.  The handler is only attached to one element (`document`, or whatever you specify as the top-level element).

Comment: each() isn't suitable for this, you want to delegate an event handler to certain attributes. All you could achieve with each() is to bind direct event handlers to each element which yes would use more memory

Comment: @Amine **you** should be the one to provide a fiddle. We have no idea about your HTML structure.

Comment: @Amine, it works fine for me.  Please be more specific than `it doesn't work`.  Also see http://jsfiddle.net/Lz4akepv/1/ for a small tweak